# What is the Master Agreement when trying to transfer an iOS app?

Tags: app-store-connect

I'm trying to transfer an app to another developer, but when I click transfer the only criteria which is not checked is Master Agreement:

[image]

Where is this Master Agreement, and how can I fix this?

Comment: At the moment I get the same too. I expect Apple will fix this over the next few days.

Comment: The Master Agreement is now check marked. I guess Apple fixed this for my account on June 12.

Comment: I know we normally close developer questions and send them to stack overflow, but we're working on getting iTunes connect questions a place to come and live, so that means some developer looking questions might arrive. Let's talk on [meta] if anyone has serious heartburn about this change.

Comment: Well, the same thing happened when Apple last updated the developer portal: It took them a few days to fix up the ability to edit provisioning profiles and some other things.

Answer (score 9):

You need to check your Contracts, Tax, and Banking information.

> To resolve this issue, you need to check your Contracts, Tax, and Banking information. If you have Request button on the page, you have to click and review it.
>
> [image]
>
> After review it and check the box then submit.

<sup>Source: [blog.jaey.ca: Master Agreement Criteria Not Met](http://blog.jaey.ca/post/iOS-App-Transfer-Issue-with-Master-Agreement-Criteria-Not-Met.aspx)</sup>

Comment: +1 This is the best answer of the group. I was able to solve the problem posted by the original question without contacting Apple support. Thanks to both @Sanghoon and @grgarside!

Comment: This worked for me as well. Make sure you wait for your contracts to finish processing though. AKA there shouldn't be any contracts in the "Contracts In Process" section. Same goes for the recipient of the transfer.

Comment: I had to sign out from iTunes Connect and sign in again so that an alert message directing me to the new agreement would show up. I think it was a bug in the site not to show it in Agreements section from the start without need to re-login.

Comment: My 1 year membership expired, so I wanted to transfer this. Do i have to have a valid membership in order to transfer?

Answer (score 0):

The correct action when you have a problem with your legal agreements is to call developer relations if it's impacting your business and you can't figure out how to solve the issue online.

- https://developer.apple.com/contact/

In this case, a widespread software issue on the Apple side could cause this. Also it could be a more narrow issue, with the software not storing the electronic agreement properly or your account is in a state of transition or error. You may need someone on the inside to either correct the records or point you to what (and when) you can resolve this yourself.

In this case, it's an account management issue so log in with your developer ID and either fill in the form or call the numbers listed for your account.

- https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php

Answer (score 0):

This happens also when you are trying to transfer paid app or app with in-app purchases and you do not have "iOS Paid Applications" or "iAD App Network" contracts in effect.

Go to "Contracts, Tax and Banking" and check (or / and request) if you have all contact, bank and tax info sorted out for them.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the requirements for transferring an app?
>
> To transfer an app, make sure that:
>
> - The **transferor and the recipient have active developer accounts** and accepted the most current version of all master agreements that are currently in effect
> - The app has at least one approved version
> - The app is in the Ready for Sale, Invalid Binary, Rejected, Developer Rejected, or Developer Removed from Sale state
> - Any associated In-App Purchases are in the Ready to Submit, Ready for Sale, Rejected, Developer Removed from Sale, or Approved state
> - You know the Apple ID of the recipient’s Team Agent and their Team ID
>
> If the app uses iAd, the transferor and the recipient must have accepted the most current version of all iAd contracts.

Pulled info from Apple's FAQ in developer center:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wo/146.0.0.13.7.2.7.9.3.1.2.3.3.1.1.3.2.1.3.0.1.0.9.0.1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, 
The IOS developer licence had recently been updated and I had to agree to it again, then this "Master Agreement" field was green and I could transfer the app.

I would recommend jumping into your Developer member center, and you can agree to the licence.

https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#updateAgreement

[image]