# Transfering app after membership expired

Tags: app-store-connect

My membership expired. And I want to trasnfer my app to my new teams account.

It keeps saying I didn't accept master agreement. I saw this topic - [What is the Master Agreement when trying to transfer an iOS app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93681/what-is-the-master-agreement-when-trying-to-transfer-an-ios-app) - but I can't seem to find this.

I get lots of warnings that my membership has expired.

Is it required to have active membership in order to transfer? (this would majorly stink, because we did all the payments on the new account)

The super weird part is, I don't have in app purchases in this app. I have no idea why it's doing this to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact developer support from the new account and ask if hey can help. I’m guessing a one time transfer if you know exactly what you need and aren’t a pain in the Apple (pita) I could see them handling the transfer or re-activating the old account for a day to effect the transfer.

Seems like you could just scrape together the $100 as you didn’t plan ahead as the worst case scenario, but perhaps work with support if you want to keep your $100 and don’t mind waiting a bit to convince someone to help you out.

The risk is Apple can’t tell you’re who you say you are and then they have to deal with an improper transfer of someone else’s intellectual property and personal information. If they are open to liability in this request, you’ll likely never convince them to transfer and have to walk away from either the renewal fee or the abandoned apps.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go and I’m sure Apple will be able to help with this. Regarding proving who you are to Apple, the expired account can still be logged into as usual, so whatever methods are used by Apple for this would still apply as usual I believe?

Comment: Emailed them, got a response yesterday, saying both have to have a active membership. I asked for one time, and they said no. I used to have active membership on this last year. :( Apple as the worst customer service. How much will tricking $100 out of me benefit them?

Answer (score 1):

Emailed them via their support form, got a response yesterday, saying both have to have a active membership. I asked for one time, and they said no. I even had active membership on this account over the last year. :( Apple as the worst customer service. How much will tricking $100 out of me benefit them?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote to Apple support (Go to: https://developer.apple.com/contact/ -> App Set Up and Distribution -> App Transfer) and they gave me a 7-day extension of membership to transfer my app.

Comment: Oh wow that is so interesting. They told me I have to get another year of membership. Wow that is ridiculous. I'll post the email they sent me here. Maybe I can request the 100 back.

Comment: @Noitidart it's so weird... I'm not sure, but maybe it's because I was in the team of the new Apple Id with prepaid membership.